# sorting list of nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have something like

```
[
    {
        "key": { "subkey1":1, "subkey2":"a"  }
    },
    {
        "key": { "subkey1":10, "subkey2":"b" }
    },
    {
        "key": { "subkey1":5, "subkey2":"c" }
    }
]
```

And would need to have :

```
[
    {
        "key": { "subkey1":10, "subkey2":"b" }
    },
    {
        "key": { "subkey1":5, "subkey2":"c" }
    },
    {
        "key": { "subkey1":1, "subkey2":"a" }
    }
]
```

Many thanks!

EDIT : I'd like to sort by subkey1, this wasn't clear previously.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `key` keyword to the [`sorted()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`sort()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
yourdata.sort(key=lambda e: e['key']['subkey'], reverse=True)
```

Demo:

```
>>> yourdata = [{'key': {'subkey': 1}}, {'key': {'subkey': 10}}, {'key': {'subkey': 5}}]
>>> yourdata.sort(key=lambda e: e['key']['subkey'], reverse=True)
>>> yourdata
[{'key': {'subkey': 10}}, {'key': {'subkey': 5}}, {'key': {'subkey': 1}}]
```

This assumes that *all* top-level dictionaries have a `key` key, which is assumed to be a dictionary with a `subkey` key.

See the [Python Sorting HOWTO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) for more details and tricks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to sort by the value of `d['key']['subkey']` for every dictionary `d` in the list, use this:

```
sorted(yourdata, key=lambda d: d.get('key', {}).get('subkey'), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it worked on a very complex nested dictionaries list. Take a bow!

Answer (score -2):

```
sorted(yourdata, reverse=True)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but you'll realise that a `dict` as an iterable returns the keys, so you won't end up with a useful list

Comment: did not understand. the output just like asked.

Comment: @alexvassel: The output in the *simple* example case happens to be the same, but if any of the dictionaries has an extra key in it, the results will be *very* different indeed. I didn't downvote your answer, but it *is* incorrect on that account.

Comment: What happens sometimes is that the question changes, although it's a valid answer in some sense... I just wouldn't worry about it... ie: you post a working solution, and then all of a sudden the question changes... and your solution doesn't work... Some people will downvote on the slightest off and others will comment that it's not workable and why (I prefer the latter)...