# sorting nested dictionary in python 2.7 on 3rd level within all groups

Tags: python-2.7

I have a following nested dictionary which is not a list of lists, but dictionary within dictionary.

```
MYDICT = {
    "groupA": {
        "teamA": {
            "won": 0,
            "lost": 1,
        },
        "teamB": {
            "won": 1,
            "lost": 2,
        }
    },
    "groupB": {
        "teamC": {
            "won": 1,
            "lost": 2,
        },
        "teamD": {
            "won": 7,
            "lost": 3,
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to sort it within each group by "won" field. The result should look like:

```
{
    "groupA": {
        "teamB": {
            "won": 1,
            "lost": 2,
        },
        "teamA": {
            "won": 0,
            "lost": 1,
        }
    },
    "groupB": {
        "teamD": {
            "won": 7,
            "lost": 3,
        },
        "teamC": {
            "won": 1,
            "lost": 2,
        }
    }
}
```

The code I tried so far was

```
newd = {k: dict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)) for k, v in MYDICT.items()}
```

but it is returning following error

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

so clearly I am probably not reaching proper level to sort.

**EDIT 1**: I don't think this is possible with only one lambda. I changed my strategy and started iterating over given levels

```
new_sorted=OrderedDict()
print('MYDICT: {}'.format(jd(MYDICT)))
for item in MYDICT:
    sorted_elements = sorted(MYDICT[item], key=lambda x: (MYDICT[item][x]['won']), reverse=True)
    for se in sorted_elements:
        print('se: {}'.format(se))
        new_sorted[item] = se
        print('MYDICT[item][se]: {}'.format(MYDICT[item][se]))
        new_sorted[item][se] = MYDICT[item][se]
        print('item: {}, sorted: {}'.format(item, sorted_elements))
```

Now when I try to assign back these values (so actually I'm creating new ordered dictionary with sorted items) I have this error:

```
MYDICT: {
    "groupA": {
        "teamA": {
            "won": 0,
            "lost": 1
        },
        "teamB": {
            "won": 1,
            "lost": 2
        }
    },
    "groupB": {
        "teamD": {
            "won": 7,
            "lost": 3
        },
        "teamC": {
            "won": 1,
            "lost": 2
        }
    }
}
se: teamB
MYDICT[item][se]: {'won': 1, 'lost': 2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ordered_dict.py", line 124, in <module>
    new_sorted[item][se] = MYDICT[item][se]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting list of nested dictionaries in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237941/sorting-list-of-nested-dictionaries-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
newd = {k: dict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True))
        for k, v in MYDICT.items()}
```

is getting there.

- The second element (value) is just `x[1]`, not `x[2]`, since tuple indexes start at 0 in Python.
- You want to sort not on the value directly, but the value’s `"won"`. That’s `x[1]["won"]`.
- You need `OrderedDict`, like your other snippet, since plain Python 2.7 dicts aren’t ordered.

So:

```
newd = {k: OrderedDict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["won"], reverse=True))
        for k, v in MYDICT.items()}
```