# Sort list of nested dictionaries by value

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I have list of dictionaries. I need to sort it. If there is no nested dictionaries in those ones, it goes well. But i need to sort nested dictionaries.

```
lis = [{"name": "Nandini", "age": {"name": "Nandini", "age": 20}},
       {"name": "Manjeet", "age": 21},
       {"name": "Nikhil", "age": 19}]

# using sorted and lambda to print list sorted
# by age
print("The list printed sorting by age: ")
print(sorted(lis, key=lambda i: i['age']))
```

So, i have the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\json\111.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(sorted(lis, key=lambda i: i['age']))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'dict'
```

But if I replace those nested dictionary, it goes well.
There is an answer how to sort by subkey: [sorting list of nested dictionaries in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237941/sorting-list-of-nested-dictionaries-in-python)
but i need a way how to sort by key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work with an `or` operator in combination with `if/else` to specify the key:

```
print(
    sorted(
        lis,
        # Uses age if it is an integer else take the 'second level' age value
        key=lambda i: i['age'] if isinstance(i['age'], int) else i['age']['age']
    )
)
```

Out:

```
The list printed sorting by age: 
[{'name': 'Nikhil', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Nandini', 'age': {'name': 'Nandini', 'age': 20}}, {'name': 'Manjeet', 'age': 21}]
```

Note:

In case you want to skip all items that have a nested 'ages' filter them out before sorting:

```
print(
    sorted(
        [item for item in lis if isinstance(item['age'], int)],
        key=lambda i: i['age']
    )
)
```

Comment: What if i just want to pass a content of nested list? When i delete else statement I have invalid syntax error. Same error with"else pass" usage.

Comment: @glu: The if/else construct is a so called 'Ternary Operator' so it needs to have an else statement. You might want to edit your question to make it clearer what you are trying to do: _'...pass a content of nested list.'_

Comment: for example, if i have list of dictionaries and the dictionaries have dictionaries inside, but I don't need the inside data, so i want to skip this internal dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle an arbitrary amount of nested dictionaries, you could use a recursive function to sort the values:

```
import sys
from pprint import pp

def getAge(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return getAge(d.get("age", None))
    elif isinstance(d, int):
        return d
    else:
        # An integer larger than any practical list or string index
        return sys.maxsize

lis = [{"name": "Nandini", "age": {"name": "Nandini", "age": 20}},
       {"name": "Manjeet", "age": 21},
       {"name": "Valodja", "age": "NotANumber"},
       {"name": "Nikhil", "age": 19}]

pp(sorted(lis, key=getAge))
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Nikhil', 'age': 19},
 {'name': 'Nandini', 'age': {'name': 'Nandini', 'age': 20}},
 {'name': 'Manjeet', 'age': 21},
 {'name': 'Valodja', 'age': 'NotANumber'}]
```