# Sorting list with 3-nested dictionaries by value

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

The answer on [Sort list of nested dictionaries by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008509/sort-list-of-nested-dictionaries-by-value)
isn't applicable with more nested data like

```
[
    {
        "primary_key": 228282,
        "success": "YES",
        "date": "2020-10-09T10:10:33.123456",
        "spec": "text text text",
        "details": {
                    "quality": "228.33",
                    "measure": {
                        "title": "kilo",
                        "sign": "kg"
                }
            },
        "address_from": "NY",
        "address_to": "CA",
    },
    
    ...
    
]
```

If I want to sort by 'date', then i have the error:

```
    [item for item in lis if isinstance(item['date'], str)],
KeyError: 'date'
```

How to sort by date in this case?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wc44gv9puwjd8t/228.json?dl=0 I have the .json file. My attempt:

```
import json

with open("operations.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
    lis = json.load(read_file)
    print(lis)

print(
    sorted(
        [item for item in lis if isinstance(item['date'], str)],
        key=lambda i: i['date']
    )
)
```

Comment: This runs fine on my end. Can you please post the full code and double check that each Dictionary in the List has a Key called "date"?

Comment: Your code works. Please [edit] the question to add a reproducible example.

Comment: @Norrius: done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there are `items` in `operations.json` that got no date key, you can define a default value (`None` for example):

```
import json

with open("operations.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
    lis = json.load(read_file)

print(
    sorted(
        [item for item in lis if isinstance(item.get('date', None), str)],
        key=lambda i: i['date']
    )
)
```

Out:

```
[{'primary_key': 228282, 'success': 'YES', 'date': '2020-10-09T10:10:33.123456', 'spec': 'text text text', 'details': {'quality': '228.33', 'measure': {'title': 'kilo', 'sign': 'kg'}}, 'address_from': 'NY', 'address_to': 'CA'}]
```

Explanation:
`item.get('date', None)`, tries to access `date`, if not available use `None`