# get record from list of dictionary with latest date python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a dict like this:

```
[{'name': 'name1' , 'date':'1997-07-16 19:20:00+01:00'},{'name': 'name3' , 'date':'2006-07-16 19:20:00+01:00'},{'name': 'name2' , 'date':'1992-07-16 19:20:00+01:00'}]
```

So want to get the latest one record from this list of object on basis of latest date and time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sorting list of nested dictionaries in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237941/sorting-list-of-nested-dictionaries-in-python)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer No finding with date and time. not finding a way to do for date and time

Comment: it works for date and time too

Comment: In case all your timezones are `+01:00` you can keep the strings to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` with `key=` parameter:

```py
data = [
    {"name": "name1", "date": "1997-07-16 19:20:00+01:00"},
    {"name": "name3", "date": "2006-07-16 19:20:00+01:00"},
    {"name": "name2", "date": "1992-07-16 19:20:00+01:00"},
]

latest = max(data, key=lambda k: k["date"])  # or min() for the opposite. Works only if all your timezones are +01:00. If not use strptime

print(latest)
```

Prints:

```py
{'name': 'name3', 'date': '2006-07-16 19:20:00+01:00'}
```

---

EDIT: To sort data:

```py
from datetime import datetime

data = [
    {"name": "name1", "date": "1997-07-16 19:20:00+01:00"},
    {"name": "name3", "date": "2006-07-16 19:20:00+01:00"},
    {"name": "name2", "date": "1992-07-16 19:20:00+01:00"},
]

data = sorted(
    data, key=lambda k: datetime.strptime(k["date"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")  # or reversed with reverse=True parameter
)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"name": "name2", "date": "1992-07-16 19:20:00+01:00"},
    {"name": "name1", "date": "1997-07-16 19:20:00+01:00"},
    {"name": "name3", "date": "2006-07-16 19:20:00+01:00"},
]
```